# Attempting to transform a javascript object into an array with multiple nests

Tags: javascript, json, nested

I have a javascript object containing:

```
var object =[{"knowledgeTime":"20180101T235959","validTime":"20180101T235959","portfolioId":"Control","type":"EQUITY_OPEN_LONG","assetId":"A","strategyId":0,"quantity":1000,"cost":100000,"contractualSettleDate":"SPECIAL","commission":2.06,"fee":1.03,"managerId":0},{"knowledgeTime":"20180101T235959","validTime":"20180101T235959","portfolioId":"Control","type":"EQUITY_OPEN_LONG","assetId":"A","strategyId":0,"quantity":1000,"cost":100000,"contractualSettleDate":"SPECIAL","commission":2.06,"fee":1.03,"managerId":0}
```

```
const keyname = ['eventHeader'];

const result = keyname.reduce((acc, date, i) => {
  acc.push([keyname, data]);
  return acc;
}, []);





                          var json_object = JSON.stringify(result);
                          document.getElementById("Object").innerHTML = json_object;
                          $('.result').append('<div id ="alert" class="alert-success"><ul class="list-group" min-width:500px><li class="list-group-item active">Result Json</li><textarea class="form-control" cols="100" rows="10">{"records:"['+json_object+'</textarea></li></div>');
                        })
                    };
                    reader.onerror = function(event) {
                      console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
                    };
                    reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
              });


        });
```

The output required is:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "common": {
        "validTime": "20180101T121222",
        "knowledgeTime": "20180101T121222"

      },
      "eventHeader": {
        "portfolioId": "Collect Acquisition Disposition Transactions",
        "type": "EQUITY_OPEN_LONG"
      },
      "details": {
        "assetId": 12,
        "custodianAccountId": 0,
        "strategyId": 0,
        "quantity": 150,
        "cost": 5001.23,
        "contractualSettleDate": "SPECIAL",
        "commission": 2.05,
        "fee": 1.03,
        "managerId": 0,
        "basketId": 0
      }
    }
```

but what I am getting is nothing close as I do not understand how to splice the needed 3 array keys into the proper spots in the object.

If anyone could assist?  The closest I have been ablo to get is to push an eventHeader key into the object - but without being able to figure out how to concat the portfolioId key value pair into it.  Sorry if this is too noob - but I'm really strugging to understand the language.  I had another version where I attempted a regex replace in the stringify but that didn't work either  I'm assuming I need to pull in each object row - splice in the keys followed by the key value pairs - but can't figure out splice.

Comment: You say you have a JS object containing..., but what you have provided is an array (with a missing closing ]). Which is it meant to be?

Comment: Also if you format your code properly with proper indentation it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
var object =[{"knowledgeTime":"20180101T235959","validTime":"20180101T235959","portfolioId":"Control","type":"EQUITY_OPEN_LONG","assetId":"A","strategyId":0,"quantity":1000,"cost":100000,"contractualSettleDate":"SPECIAL","commission":2.06,"fee":1.03,"managerId":0},{"knowledgeTime":"20180101T235959","validTime":"20180101T235959","portfolioId":"Control","type":"EQUITY_OPEN_LONG","assetId":"A","strategyId":0,"quantity":1000,"cost":100000,"contractualSettleDate":"SPECIAL","commission":2.06,"fee":1.03,"managerId":0}];

const getObject = (array) => {
  const newArray = array.map(obj => {
    const { validTime, knowledgeTime, portfolioId, type, assetId, custodianAccountId, strategyId, quantity, cost, contractualSettleDate, commission, fee, managerId, basketId } = obj;
    const newObject = {
      common: { 
         validTime,
         knowledgeTime
      },
      eventHeader: {
        portfolioId,
        type
      },
      details: {
        assetId,
        custodianAccountId,
        strategyId,
        quantity,
        cost,
        contractualSettleDate,
        commission,
        fee,
        managerId,
        basketId
      }
    };
    return newObject;
  })
  return { records: newArray };
}
const requeiredOutput = getObject(object);
console.log(requeiredOutput);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexsandr - another easy to understand solution.

Comment: Alexander - another quick questionn - I hope - but I am working on a similar structure with another object - except in this case - I need a key value pair inn front of the records.  Meaning the output above - bbut withh a { key: value, records [.  Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to do, but if it's what I think it is then this is a solution:

```js
const sourceArray = [
  {
    knowledgeTime: '20180101T235959',
    validTime: '20180101T235959',
    portfolioId: 'Control',
    type: 'EQUITY_OPEN_LONG',
    assetId: 'A',
    strategyId: 0,
    quantity: 1000,
    cost: 100000,
    contractualSettleDate: 'SPECIAL',
    commission: 2.06,
    fee: 1.03,
    managerId: 0,
  },
  {
    knowledgeTime: '20180101T235959',
    validTime: '20180101T235959',
    portfolioId: 'Control',
    type: 'EQUITY_OPEN_LONG',
    assetId: 'A',
    strategyId: 0,
    quantity: 1000,
    cost: 100000,
    contractualSettleDate: 'SPECIAL',
    commission: 2.06,
    fee: 1.03,
    managerId: 0,
  },
];

const commonKeys = ['validTime', 'knowledgeTime'];
const eventHeaderKeys = ['portfolioId', 'type'];

function createNestedObj(obj) {
  const nestedObj = {common: {}, eventHeader: {}, details: {}};
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (commonKeys.includes(key)) {
      nestedObj.common[key] = val;
    } else if (eventHeaderKeys.includes(key)) {
      nestedObj.eventHeader[key] = val;
    } else {
      nestedObj.details[key] = val;
    }
  }
  return nestedObj;
}

const output = {records: []};

for (const item of sourceArray) {
  const nestedObj = createNestedObj(item);
  output.records.push(nestedObj);
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.  This worked perfectly - after posting I spent a few hours trying to get something similar to work - and could push the new keys (common, eventHeader) but was stuck on structuring it.  This worked like a charm!